# Error al hacer peticion a api con usuario y contraseña JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Tengo un api que pide usuario y contraseña para poderla consumirla:

[image: Usuario y contraseña apirest]

Como es obvio tengo los accesos, desde el navegador puedo ver perfectamente cada petición e incluso desde postman agregandole el header Authorization: Basic [User:Pasword en base64], he intentado usando axios en una app hecha en VUE pero me fue imposible, ahora lo intento en usando AJAX de esta forma:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://url.api/v1", true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader(
"Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password'),
);
xhr.onload = function () {
console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

Y me sigue dando error 401:

[image: Error401]

Me he dado cuenta que nunca se envia la cabecera Authorization cuando uso la direccion de la API, pero si cuando uso otra de prueba:

Esta es al cabecera que se envia cuando uso la api que debo usar:

[image: Header1]

Como se observa no aparece por ningun la cabecera Authorization, pero si cambio por ejemplo a una api como JsonPlaceHolder si la recibe:

[image: Header2]

Alguna sugerencia de porque no puedo enviar el header?

Comment: ¿La documentación de la API no te explica cómo hacer las peticiones con autorización?

Comment: No, en la documentación solo se habla de pasar el header: Authorization nada mas, lo raro es que desde postman funciona bien, pero de ninguna manera he logrado que acepte el header cuando hago la peticion desde JS

Comment: Trata de imprimir el mensaje de error de la petición para ver cuál es la causa de que no funcione.

Comment: Editando el post con el error.

Comment: Post editado con el error.

Comment: Pero ¿la API no tiene documentación?  ¿Estás seguro que la misma admite peticiones tipo CORS?

Comment: No sobre eso en específico, lo único que hay en la documentación son las rutas para acceder y pues que se precisa añadir el header de authorization pero nada más, el error parece ser restrictivo por parte de la api no? Pero entonces porque desde Postman si se puede, me queda la duda.

Comment: El **servidor** en el que estás almacenando la APP/Web debe permitir CORS. Recomiendo buscar la documentación sobre como implementar este en tu servidor específico.